# Draggable element behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in Mozilla Firefox It is a little part of a bigger project. When I drag the P text into my DIV and this DIV doesn't have a child, the P text is put into the DIV normally, but when the DIV already has the child P and I try to put the P text into the DIV (of course you have to point the empty space inside the DIV, don't point the P tag child again), the page tries to load an url with the ID of the P text (i don't know why).

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {

    if($(ev.target).children().is('p')){
    //you are pointing the DIV and it has a P child
    
    }else{
      ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
                ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
span {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<p>Drag the text into the rectangle to see what happens:</p>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<p id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">DRAGGABLE TEXT</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it by using the ev.preventDefault(). This method prevents the default action of the browser that is to reload the page going to an url with the ID of the draggable element, if the draggable element is an image, it will go to the source of the image. It only happens in Mozilla Firefox.